# "ta_IN" not found in Locale.getAvailableLocales() for multilanguage support in Struts 2

Tags: java, struts2

I'm developing a webpage with multi language support in Struts 2.

The code is working if I select English, Chinese etc. But it's not working if I choose  `ta_IN` locale (Language: Tamil, Country: India). Even `Locale.getAvailableLocales()` does not return `ta_IN`.

Please help me to resolve this.

I am using `struts2-core-2.3.1.2.jar` and Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that the `ta_IN` locale is just not supported in Java, so there's probably not much you can do about it.

Oracle provides a [list of all locales supported in Java 8](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/java8locales-2095355.html).